# Consecutive pointer assignment with post-increment

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I came across this piece of code in *C*:

```
*p++=*q++=*r++;
```

In my opinion it's erroneous because I can't recall any rule in C specifying when the `++` after q should be actually conducted - before the assignment between `*p++` and `*q++`, or after?

Therefore my impression is that this may very likely be an *undefined behavior*, but could not pinpoint where exactly in the *C* standards (*C89 or C99*) this is accounted for.

This is where help from language cops is really appreciated. Please shed light.

Comment: It doesn't matter: the value of `q++` is the value of `q` before the increment.  `q` is a pointer, the assignment is to whatever q was pointing to.  Looks like the inner loop of a cute li'l two-fer `strcpy()`, `while (*p++=*q++=*r++){}` will make two copies of the `r` string at `p` and `q`.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of this code does not depend at all on when the `++` is physically carried out. The behavior is well-defined.

The fact that the *postfix* form of increment is used simply means that the *original* values of pointers are used as results of increment. I.e. the whole thing is equivalent to

```
old_p = p;
old_q = q;
old_r = r;

*old_p = *old_q = *old_r;

p = p + 1;
q = q + 1;
r = r + 1;
```

Note that you can freely move the physical increments around in completely arbitrary fashion, as in

```
old_p = p;
old_q = q;
old_r = r;

p = p + 1;
q = q + 1;

*old_p = *old_q = *old_r;

r = r + 1;
```

The semantics of the code does not change, as long as the *original* pointer values are used in the assignment.

Also note that the original value does have to be *stored* to be available in assignment. The compiler is free to recover that original value by re-evaluating it through decrement. I.e. the compiler can even translate your expression into something like

```
p = p + 1;
q = q + 1;

*(p - 1) = *(q - 1) = *r;

r = r + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are incrementing three different pointer variables, the overall behaviour is perfectly well defined (assuming the pointers all point to valid storage locations).  It is not specified whether the increment of `r` takes place before or after the assignment to `p`, but that doesn't affect the result, either.

For convenience, suppose we have:

```
char buffer1[10];
char buffer2[10];
char buffer3[] = "abc";
char *p = buffer1;
char *q = buffer2;
char *r = buffer3;

*p++ = *q++ = *r++;
```

After this has executed, all of these assertions are safe:

```
assert(p == buffer1 + 1);  // Or p == &buffer1[1];
assert(q == buffer2 + 1);  // Or q == &buffer2[1];
assert(r == buffer3 + 1);  // Or r == &buffer3[1];
assert(*r == 'b');
assert(buffer1[0] == 'a');
assert(buffer2[0] == 'a');
```

Comment: assuming the pointers all point to **distinct** valid storage locations

Comment: Please explain the undefined behaviour if (1) `p`, `q` and `r` point to the same place, and (2) if `p` and `q` point to the same place and `r` points somewhere else. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.2 Expressions ¶2 _If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings._

Comment: Hmm, but he was asking in terms of C89 and C99, the bad old days of sequence points where (if I recall) modifying any object twice between sequence points was UB. +1 anyway.

Comment: Interesting. (I misquoted the section number in the 2011 standard; is is just §6.5 Expressions — not §6.5.2).  The corresponding paragraph in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.5 Expressions ¶2 _Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
shall be read only to determine the value to be stored._ This seems to rule out defined behaviour when `p` and `q` point to the same object; I am not sure about `r` being the same as one of `p` or `q`. I wonder if the difference is intentional?

Comment: The change in semantics was definitely intentional. It was a well-known "bug" and it was fixed simultaneously in C++11. (In practice, an older compiler will never take the opportunity to misbehave, and the standard was just changed to bless existing practice.)

Answer (score 1):

Assignment has [lower precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) than both `*` and `++`(*both post and pre*) so assignment will happen afterwards but the order of evaluation of the operands to `=` is unspecified which should not matter in this case unless `r`, `p` or `q` point to the same location in which case you would have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) anyway since you would be modifying the same object more than once within the same sequence point.

The C99 draft standard section `6.5.16` *Assignment operators* paragraph *3* says:

> [...]The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand shall
>   occur between the previous and the next sequence point.[...]

and paragraph *4* says:

> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. [...]

Answer (score 0):

If I am  not mistaken, post-increment is always performed at the end of the assignment

i.e

> increment in *r
>
> *q<-*r
>
> increment in *q
>
> *p<-*q
>
> increment in *p

"[It is important to note that a postfix increment or decrement expression evaluates to the value of the expression prior to application of the respective operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1e3921c.aspx)"

Comment: post-increment is applied sometime between the evaluation and the next sequence point; "at the end of the assignment" sounds too specific.